# Numbering the strings in a list of strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I have to number each string in list of strings

Like this:

```
numberLines ["one", "two", "three"] 
   ==> ["1: one", "2: two", "3: three"]
```

I tried this:

```
numberLines = map (\g -> (x + 1) : g) where
 x = 0
```

but of course it didn't work

Comment: You can work with `zipWith`.

Comment: you should be able to fix your attempt with `mapAccumL`.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell variables are *immutable*, so you can not change the value of a variable like in an imperative language like Python.

You can for example use [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) to zip the list of strings together with a list of `Int`s:

```
numberLines :: [String] -> [String]
numberLines = zipWith f [1 :: Int .. ]
    where f i s = show i ++ ' ' : ':' : s
```

Here `f` thus takes an `Int` and a `String` and produces a string `"i: s"` with *`i`* the string representation of the number, and *`s`* the string.